# How to not slow down even after generating a lot of custom markers on google map swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-maps-markers

I've made a custom gmsmarker so that I can put a number on the center of the marker. However, when I populate a lot of custom markers, the map slows down on loading and dragging. I would think that it's because I am drawing UIView every time I create a marker. Is there another way that I can do this more efficiently?

[image]

Comment: how much is 'a lot'? possibly you have to use 'marker clustering' to reduce number of elements on map

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/utility/marker-clustering

Comment: in the hundreds....even 50 slows the map down. this is after clustering...

Comment: did you try do it without 'alpha: 0.8' and/or 'masksToBounds'? masking/blending takes a lot cpu time

Comment: maskToBounds is commented out so no worrying about that, but I kinda need the alpha...is there a way to solve the issue without having to change alpha to 1.0?